# ValueError with entry-field. Tkinter math-program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

writing a tkinter program for my kids to do some math.
It first shows a label with the math-question, for example "What is 5  + 3?"

Then an inputfield (entry) shows to get the answer (entry-field checks if integers are entered)

A Button is created to start a function to check the solution.

Function to create random numbers and create entry-field:

```
 def Do_Math(self):
    nr1 = random.choice(self.numbers) #random number from list
    nr2 = random.choice(self.numbers) #random number from list
    do_math = nr1 + nr2 #do the math
    txt_som = Label(tk, text = 'wat is de som van ' + str(nr1) + ' en ' + str(nr2) + ' ?', state='normal', \
                             font=('Courier', 14, "bold"), justify=LEFT, padx = 10, background='LightCyan2')
    txt_som.place(x = 20, y = 170)
    tk.update()

    oplossing = Entry(tk, validate="key")  #create input-field  #validate to check for integer
    oplossing['validatecommand'] = (oplossing.register(self.testVal),'%P','%d') #validate to check for integer
    oplossing.place(x = 20, y = 200)   #place inputfield on screen
    oplossing.focus_set()   #set focus so user can directly input.
    self.oplossing = oplossing
    self.do_math = do_math

    #knop voor ingeven oplossing:
    knop_oplossing = Button(tk, text='Ok?', command=self.solution) #create button
    knop_oplossing.place(x = 20, y = 250) #place button on screen
    tk.update()
```

Function to check the solution:
If the solution is good then the above function runs again to create new numbers.

```
def solution(self):
    while True:
        if int(self.oplossing.get()) == self.do_math:
            #self.oplossing.delete(0, END)  #clear entr-value
            play.random_sound('good')
            self.lbl.place(self.lbl.pi) #Place label
            self.lbl_w.place_forget() #Hide label
            tk.update()
            #global score
            #score = score + 1
            #print('GOED GEDAAN!', score, 'van', asked_maths, 'pogingen goed')
            game.Do_Math() #Choose new random numbers

        elif int(self.oplossing.get()) != self.do_math:
            play.random_sound('wrong')
            self.lbl.place_forget() #Hide label
            self.lbl_w.place(self.lbl_w.pi) #Place label
            tk.update()
            break #Go out the while loop and do nothing
```

Every runs ok, but in the background i get following error every time the solution is good:

> if int(self.oplossing.get()) == self.do_math:
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I think the problem is that the function "solution" tries this:

> int(self.oplossing.get()) == self.do_math
>   but the entry-field has no value jet.

What do you think? I wanna solve these error messages before going further.

Thnx in advanced!

Comment: The problem is that `self.oplossing.get()` is returning an empty string. You then try to convert it to an int.

Comment: That’s indeed the problem.  Would the solution be to build an try-except routine? 
I find it strange that when the program runs first no error is fired. When the function runs for the second time it prints the error.